# Two photos disappeared from my Gallery

Tags: gallery

Yesterday I noticed that two specific photos I wanted to preserve disappeared, I remember I didn't delete them because I didn't find them in the trash bin, nor did I delete them from the trash bin itself because it was the first time I checked there.
What is it due to? How can I retrieve them? (Out of 500 photos I have, those two got deleted, arghh)

I'm 100% sure I didn't delete them, furthermore I took these pictures less than 30 days ago, so even if I deleted them, I'd have found them in the trash folder, and I haven't.

Comment: It is possible that the camera APP had an internal problem when try to save these photos.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you mean that Camera didn't save these photos directly on the spot and weren't save from the get-go? I mean, I saw them saved and even visualised them in the gallery, but then suddenly disappeared and I'm unable to retrieve them for the moment, I've tried to see solutions across web and YT but nothing. It's not that I take pictures and do not get saved, it's peculiar for these two photos.

Comment: Thanks for the info @abdul. Please, could you share with us more information about the device that you are using, the gallery app, and if you are using SD Card?

Comment: You can try recovering those using deleted photo recovery deleted file recovery apps available on Play Store

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a File Manager app and  look for your photo in one of the following folders:

For photos you took by your phone:
DCIM

For images you received by WhatsApp:
WhatsApp > Media > WhatsApp Images